# O que significa a expressão "Haver vamos"?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Gostaria de saber se é correto dizer "haver vamos" para significar "vamos ver" ou se tem outro significado ou ainda se é uma expressão mal formada.

Comment: Não conheço a frase, mas: como "haver" não significa "ver", "a ver vamos" faria mais sentido, mas parece fazer mais sentido ainda em espanhol, onde se diz "vamos a ver" em vez de "vamos ver".

Comment: Muito obrigado. Foi muito útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão é "**a ver vamos**", e tem exatamente o significado indicado por DanGetz no comentário: "vamos a ver", "veremos".

Veja-se a [entrada para "ver"](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ver) no dicionário Priberam:

> a ver vamos
>
> - Expressão usada para indicar que se espera ou se deve esperar pelo desenrolar dos acontecimentos.

"ver", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/ver [consultado em 10-05-2020].

Comment: Muito obrigado. Foi muito útil.